# Simulator for AD8232 Chip

Tags: simulator

How can I get AD8232 chip in Arduino simulator?
It is because I have my ciruit comprising AD8232 analogue chip but I dont get this chip? I want to make simulatoin of my ciruit.
If it is can not be found in Arduino please direct me in which circuit simulating software can I get it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there would be an actual simulator for this chip. Its hard. But there is a way around.

What you are doing eventually is **ECG** and the output given by this chip is just analog signal i.e. **a single float value**. So, lets say for now, all you are concerned with is obtaining those float **values** irrespective of source. And of course you need a lot of them.

What you can do is to use a **dataset**. As indicated by its name, a **dataset** contains a large number of (recorded) value of something.

So, you can use a **dataset for heart reate** to **simulate** this chip.

There are many related **datasets** available online for free. just [Google it](https://www.google.com.pk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dataset%20heart%20rate). and find one that suits you.

Hope it help. Thanks.